# C++ no suitable conversion function from "Date" to "Date (*)()" exists

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I'm working on a payroll program but I keep stumbling on this one error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      no suitable conversion function from "Date" to "Date (*)()" exists  Payroll c:\Users\Bart\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Payroll\Payroll\Payroll.cpp 58

Here's my main:

```
int main()
{
int count = 0;
int option = 0;
int month;
int day;
int year;

cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

Employee *employees[arraySize];

cout << "Welcome to the payroll program!" << endl;

cout << "Please enter the current month: ";
cin >> month;

cout << "Please enter the current day: ";
cin >> day;

cout << "Please enter the current month: ";
cin >> year;

Date currentDate(month, day, year);

while (option != 3)
{
    cout << endl << "Please select one of the following options" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Enter new employee information" << endl;
    cout << "2 - View payroll" << endl;
    cout << "3 - Exit the application" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your option: ";
    cin >> option;

    switch (option)
    {
        case 1:
            if (count < arraySize)
                {
                    count+= createEmployee(employees, count, currentDate);
                    //This is where the error is occurring, currentDate is underlined
                }
            else
            {
                cout << "You cannot enter any more than " << arraySize << " employees." << endl;
            }
                break;
        case 2:
            displayEmployees(employees, count);
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Please enter a valid menu selection";
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

And here is the first part of my createEmployee method:

```
int createEmployee(Employee *employees[], int index, Date date())
{
string firstName;
string middleName;
string lastName;
int bDay;
int bMonth;
int bYear;
Date currentDate = date();
string SSN;
int option;
```

Comment: You have to show declaration and definition of `Date`

Comment: Minimal compilable example.

Comment: In the line `int createEmployee(Employee *employees[], int index, Date date())` the last parameter seems incorrect to me. Maybe, you mean `int createEmployee(Employee *employees[], int index, Date date)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eissa N. says, compiler thinks you are trying to pass object of type `Date` as a function pointer `Date(*)()`.

Remove the `()` from `Date date()` in `createEmployee` function definition (and declaration).

Other solution would be to fix the `createEmployee` definition to accept `Date (*date)(month, day, year)` function pointer and pass function `createDate` to it and pass arguments to it in `createEmployee` function. (you would have to define createDate a function)

Comment: OTOH, the code `Date currentDate = date();` suggests that it was meant to be a function

Comment: If current date is a function then it's missing arguments. in `Date currentDate = date()` line
Or currentDate is defined in a wrong way and it should return current date without receiving any arguments.

Comment: I think I'm actually retarded. But that's what I get for trying to do this till 7 am. Anyways thanks for the help

Comment: @Anže `Date currentDate = date()` is not necessarily wrong; it can be a functor, meaning that the object `Date` defines an `operator()` to make theat code valid.

Comment: @Eissa N. good point, I completely forgot about operator overloading